# How to lag values by number of days in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a data table:

```
id    dt          val1   val2
1   '2014-01-01'  100     200 
2   '2014-01-01'  100     200
3   '2014-01-01'  100     200
4   '2014-01-01'  100     200
...
9   '2014-01-14'  1000   1100
10  '2014-01-14'  1000   1100
```

There are 100 rows - a val1 and val2 for each of ten id's for ten days.

I need to prepare a set of lagged values by id for a variable number of days.  For example, if I wanted a two day lag, I would see the following:

```
id    dt          val1   val2  val1_lag  val2_lag
1   '2014-01-01'  100     200    NA         NA
2   '2014-01-01'  100     200    NA         NA
...
1   '2014-01-03'  300     400    100       200
2   '2014-01-03'  300     400    100       200
...
1   '2014-01-09'  500     600    300       400
...
9   '2014-01-14'  1000   1100    800       900
```

Note that on January 9th, the previous value is from January 4th.  There is no date exactly two days prior, so it returns the value that is closest to January 7th (January 9th minus two days) without being greater than January 7th.  Mechanically happens on every day.  For example, on January 3rd, the values from January 1st are used, since they are the closest to January 3rd minus two days.

There is one complication.  There is no guarantee that the lagged date will be *exactly* the lagged value because of weekends and holidays.  I want the most recent value which is *at least x days earlier*.

Is there a way to do this using the power of data tables?  You can build the test table using:

```
library(data.table)
a <- rep(c(1:10), 10)
b <- rep(c(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), by = 1, len = 4), seq(as.Date("2014-01-09"), by = 1, len = 6)), 10)
c <- rep(seq(100, by = 100, len = 10), 10)
d <- rep(seq(200, by = 100, len = 10), 10)
e <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
colnames(e) <- c("id", "dt", "val1", "val2")
setDT(e)
setkeyv(e, c("id", "dt"))
```

My instinct says to use something like this formula to create the lagged values, I'm just struggling with a way to to do it automatically for multiple columns:

`setDT(e)[, ??][by = id]`

**EDIT:**
I changed my code to reflect a potential gap in dates caused by weekends, holidays, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the *complication*. I don't think you have that complication in your test data. The best thing to do would be creating a test data **with** that complication included and then provide your desired output

Comment: Did you skim through the `zoo` package?

Comment: Carl, what do you recommend I look at?

Comment: You didn't provide desired output

Comment: Maybe convert your data to a `zoo` object and use `lag`.  Just a thought.

Comment: I still don't understand. You said you want to lagged values by `id`, but in your example data you only have one unique date per each `id`...

Comment: After thinking about it, I'm just going to lag it by *x* observations rather than the actual dates.  Thanks guys!

Comment: If you would provide a *minimal reproducible code* (one we can copy and paste and work with) and the corresponding output, I'd be willing to give this a try.. I think this is a case of rolling joins in `data.table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a different minimal example that may be easier to understand (and covers more cases).

```
library(data.table)
lag <- 2;
dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2), 
                 dt = as.Date(c("2014-1-1", "2014-1-4", "2014-1-6", "2014-1-7", "2014-1-1", "2014-1-10")),
                 val1 = sample(10, 6),
                 val2 = sample(10, 6))
dt
   id         dt val1 val2
1:  1 2014-01-01    8    7
2:  1 2014-01-04   10    5
3:  1 2014-01-06    3    3
4:  1 2014-01-07    7    2
5:  2 2014-01-01    2    1
6:  2 2014-01-10    5    6

dt1 <- copy(dt)
dt1[, laggedDate:=dt]
setkey(dt1, "id", "laggedDate")

dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt2[, laggedDate:=dt-2]
setkey(dt2, "id", "laggedDate")

setnames(dt1, c("dt","val1", "val2"), c("dt.lagged", "val1.lagged", "val2.lagged"))
dt1[dt2, roll=TRUE]
   id laggedDate  dt.lagged val1.lagged val2.lagged         dt val1 val2
1:  1 2013-12-30       <NA>          NA          NA 2014-01-01    8    7
2:  1 2014-01-02 2014-01-01           8           7 2014-01-04   10    5
3:  1 2014-01-04 2014-01-04          10           5 2014-01-06    3    3
4:  1 2014-01-05 2014-01-04          10           5 2014-01-07    7    2
5:  2 2013-12-30       <NA>          NA          NA 2014-01-01    2    1
6:  2 2014-01-08 2014-01-01           2           1 2014-01-10    5    6
```

The key here is to use data.table's rolling join functionality.  If you're uncomfortable with that, check out [this blog post](http://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins/).

Comment: This is perfect, and a great explanation, thank you.